# Unable to create directory on wordpress with xampp

Tags: 16.04, xampp, wordpress

I have installed WordPress with Xampp. Now when i am trying to upload image in wordpress it shows the following errors.
`Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/08. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`
what should i do?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Linux ownership of the directory. To do this, you need to know the owner of the `httpd`/`apache` process. You can get this by typing:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

or

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

Normally the owner is `nobody` or `daemon`.

Then `cd` into your `wp-content` directory. E.g.:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content
```

and create the `uploads` directory:

```
mkdir uploads
```

You will then need to set this directory's owner to the user that is running `apache`. E.g.:

```
sudo chown daemon uploads
```

Try your upload again and it should be working.